# Anyone familiar with the html related with skype below?

Tags: html, skype

```
<span width="15px" height="12px" class="skype_name_highlight_offline" title="name"><span class="skype_name_mark"> begin_of_the_skype_highlighting
```

There is no such code ,but visible in DOM ,anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is from Skype plugin installed in your browser. It convert any Skype strings into skype buttons or something like this.